# fiz um contador de clicks e ao armazena-lo no database via ajax, o valor sempre vai para o mesmo item na tabela

Tags: mysql, ajax, contador, codeigniter-3

Preciso que ao salvar esse item no banco de dados ele seja salvo no seu respectivo produto com o id, mas não sei o que estou fazendo de errado.

**route**

```
$route['product_out_click/(:any)']         = 'panel_admin_inventory/product_out_click/$1';
```

**controller**

```
public function product_out_click($id)
    {
        $this->load->model("inventory/Products_Outside_Model");
        $data['clicks'] = $this->input->post('clicks');
        if ($this->Products_Outside_Model->countClicks($id, $data)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', "Produto editado com sucesso!");
        }
        else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('danger', "Produto não editado!");
        }
    }
```

**model**

```
public function countClicks($id, $data) {
        $query =  $this->db->get_where("products_outside", array('id' => $id));

        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $clicks = $row->clicks;
        }
        
        $qtd = $clicks;
        
        $qtd = $qtd+1;

        $data['clicks'] = $qtd;

        $query = $this->db->update("products_outside", $data, array('id' => $id));
        return $query;

        
    }
```

**view**

```
<a  class="product_out_count" onClick="onClick()">
 <button class="btn btn-xs btn-soft-primary font-size-1 text-uppercase" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Compre agora">Comprar</button>
</a>
<input type="number" class="form-control d-none" name="clicks" id="<?php echo $product_out_search['id']; ?>">
```

**javascript**

```
function onClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        var input_id = $("[name='clicks']").attr("id");
        getElementById(input_id).value = clicks;
      }

      $('.product_out_count').on('click',function(){
        var input_id = $("[name='clicks']").attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>product_out_click/"+ input_id,
            method:"POST",
            data:{},
            success:function(response){
                // on success do something
            }                    
        });
        
      });
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1):

Bom depois de muito pesquisar acabei encontrando a resposta.

**route**

```
$route['product_out_click/(:any)']         = 'panel_admin_inventory/product_out_click/$1';
```

**controller**

```
public function product_out_click()
    {
        $id = $this->input->get('id');
        
        $this->load->model("inventory/Products_Outside_Model");
        echo $id;
        if ($this->Products_Outside_Model->countClicks($id)) {
        }
        else {
        }
    }
```

**model**

```
public function countClicks($id) {
        $query =  $this->db->get_where("products_outside", array('id' => $id));

        $clicks = $query->result()[0]->clicks;
        
        $qtd = $clicks;
        
        $qtd = $qtd+1;

        $data['clicks'] = $qtd;

        $query = $this->db->update("products_outside", $data, array('id' => $id));
        return $query;

        
    }
```

**view**

```
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $product_out_search['store_link']; ?>"  class="product_out_count" >
 <button class="btn btn-xs btn-soft-primary font-size-1 text-uppercase" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Compre agora" onClick=onTheClick(<?=$product_out_search["id"];?>)>Comprar</button>
</a>
```

**javascript**

```
function onTheClick(theId){
      var clicks = 0;
      clicks += 1;
      $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>panel_admin_inventory/product_out_click?id="+ theId,
        method:"POST",
        data:{},
        success:function(response){
            // on success do something
        }                    
      });
    }
```